# Javascript Typewriter effect for multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html

I found a nice [typewriter effect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp) that prints text when you click the button and it works nicely. However if I want to create multiple buttons that print different texts using this script, it just doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Text goes here';


var speed = 20;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="typeWriter()">CLICK HERE</a>

<p id="txt"></p>
```

Comment: You only have one button in the code you posted..?

Comment: My bad, I only posted the code for one paragraph. In an attempt to create two I just duplicated the code except for each I made sure the names of the variable "txt", the <p> id, and the function name "typeWriter" were all different. I essentially only posted one piece of code because I don't know how I'd write it to make two work at once.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the function to look more like this (basically, everything that was global should be a parameter of the function instead)

You'll also need to change the function call a bit as a result - see the snippet below.

```js
function typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos = 0) {
  if (currentPos < messageToShow.length) {
    document.getElementById(targetElement).innerHTML += messageToShow.charAt(currentPos);
    currentPos++;
    setTimeout(function() { typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos); }, timeBetween);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="typeWriter('Hello world', 'demo', 100)">Click me</button>
<button onclick="typeWriter('Other message', 'demo2', 100)">click me two</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer a slightly more flexible approach:

First of all, create an array of the strings you'd like to have appear with a type writer effect:

```
const texts = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '1234567890`-=[]#&;./,\!"£$'];
```

You can see above, that the array has two strings in it. Next loop over the strings. I've done so by calling the `forEach` method of the array:

```
texts.forEach(text =>
{
  //work happens here
});
```

So for each of the strings, create a `div` with an `a`, to click on, and a `p` to write in.

```
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', '#');
  a.innerHTML = 'Type writer go!';
  div.appendChild(a);
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  div.appendChild(p);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Then for the `a` add a click listener, that will start the typewriter effect.

```
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextUpdate(p, 0, text);
  });
```

As you can see, the click handler calls a function called `nextUpdate`. This function sets the current text of the `p` and sets the timeout for the next update.

```
function nextUpdate(p, index, text)
{
  p.innerHTML = text.substr(0, index);

  if(index < text.length)
  {
    setTimeout(nextUpdate, speed, p, index+1, text);
  }
}
```

The `if` there check to see if the string has been completely written. If it has not then the timeout is set up to call `nextUpdate` again, and the same parameters are passed, but with an increase in the `index` parameter, which tells the functions how much of the string to read.

```js
const texts = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '1234567890`-=[]#&;./,\!"£$'];
const speed = 150;

//create the document
texts.forEach(text =>
{
  //create the area that the type writer will go
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', '#');
  a.innerHTML = 'Type writer go!';
  div.appendChild(a);
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  div.appendChild(p);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  
  //set the onclick of the link
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextUpdate(p, 0, text);
  });
});

function nextUpdate(p, index, text)
{
  p.innerHTML = text.substr(0, index);
  if(index < text.length)
  {
    setTimeout(nextUpdate, speed, p, index+1, text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure how having to define a constant array of strings makes it 'more flexible' but it does work...